# How do I dynamically create a list of target filenames in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list of files that have a certain string in them in a .csv format but my list only stores the last of all the filenames despite within the loop it prints each file name.

I have tried creating a list then outputting it as a csv but the only thing that is output is the last element of the list.

```
for fname in glob.glob('*.txt'):   
  if os.path.isfile(fname):    
    with open(fname) as f:   
        for line in f:       
            if 'target' in line:    
                mylist = []
                mylist.append(fname)
                #print ('found code in file %s' %fname)
                print(mylist)
                with open("out.csv","w") as l:
                    wr = csv.writer(l,delimiter="\n")
                    wr.writerow(mylist)
                    break
```

The output of this code is

```
['target_1.txt']
['target_3.txt']
```

I want this is csv form but when I look at the out.csv file there is only target_3.txt in the file.
What I want is a csv with rows:

```
['target_1.txt']
['target_3.txt']
```

Comment: Everytime you do `open("out.csv","w")` you're overwriting the entire file each time... so it's only going to contain the contents of whatever you last wrote to it... You probably want to open the file outside the loop.....

Comment: How do I change that? Would I append to a csv?

Comment: Open the file *once* even before you start doing `for fname in...`

Comment: (and I suspect you want `wr.writerows` (note the **s**) instead of `wr.writerow...`)

Comment: @JonClements might be easier for him to understand if you put it as an answer.

Comment: @Nick feel free to do that if you fancy doing so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the difference in indentation. Instead of doing the second `with` inside the `for` loop, do it at the same indentation level, i.e. after you have finished looping.

```py
mylist = []
for fname in glob.glob('*.txt'):
  if os.path.isfile(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'target' in line:
                mylist.append(fname)
                #print ('found code in file %s' %fname)
                break
with open("out.csv","w") as l:
    wr = csv.writer(l,delimiter="\n")
    wr.writerows(mylist)
```

Notice also how we create `mylist` before the `for` loop; you would overwrite the previous value of this list (too) inside the loop. As noted in a comment, I also changed `writerow` to `writerows` to write all the collected rows.

Answer (score 2):

Taking @JonClements comments and posting as an answer to make it easier to understand what he's saying.

```
with open("out.csv","w") as l:                # Open "out.csv" ONCE
    for fname in glob.glob('*.txt'):   
        if os.path.isfile(fname):    
            with open(fname) as f:   
                for line in f:       
                    if 'target' in line:    
                        mylist = []
                        mylist.append(fname)
                        #print ('found code in file %s' %fname)
                        print(mylist)
                        wr = csv.writer(l,delimiter="\n")
                        wr.writerows(mylist)
                        break
```